# Is there a way to automatically arrange a collection of small images into a collage, with customizable parameters?

Tags: logo, images, software-recommendation, automation, composition

For a project I'm working on I want to take 40-50 music band logos, and arrange them into a collage in a specific area of an image. Example from online below:

[image]

Below you can see an example of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

And I want to do this for 20-25 other genres. Sometimes the band logos are not too weird and it's easy to put them into a presentable collage, but sometimes I have to spend hours figuring out the best way to arrange them. So is there an automatic way to do this? All the band logos are individual transparent images whose selection layers/boxes correspond only to whatever is visible, so is there an algorithm or method that can take as inputs the individual logos, available area/final collage size, maybe some parameters like maximum distance between images, and output something similar to my second image but in the most efficient/"geometrically logical" way possible?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Adobe Photoshop has a plugin called Contact Sheet II, which can be used to create a collage.  Maybe check youtube for tutorials. There's one here: https://youtu.be/M0oPMeYzEW0

Comment: While there are ways to automate placement of images, I wouldn't be surprised if the second image had human intervention. You could start with a grid of images, but you will probably have to manually resize and move images around to make sure each logo has the same emphases.

Comment: Or if you have GIMP (which is free), there's a plugin called G'MIC which can be used to make a collage/montage. See tutorial here: https://youtu.be/JJ_WH6d7cbs you won't need to the whole tutorial, just the montage part.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thank you, the Contact Sheet II solution is what I want. I still have to manually make the images the same size but that makes sense, there's no objective way to compare their sizes other than visually, considering every logo's variation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WidsMob Montage is a software that can arrange any number of photos within any container, all you have to do is to load the music Band logos and determie the container (in your case it will be simple rectangle) and set the spacing between the logos and if they interlace or simple tile.
and in your case you shoud select a small number of photos in row and colum and a black rectangle as your big image (container)
you can check the software on the following [link](https://www.widsmob.com/montage)

and to enrich the subject .. all you need is a "mosaic Photo" creator software and there is so many in the market. some are online free service like https://mosaically.com/

Comment: This software does what I'm looking for, but for some reason it doesn't open after installation. It would normally answer the question, so thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

[Shape Collage Pro](http://www.shapecollage.com/) is the tool i've used for collages - althought the shape part of it never really excited me. Set a grid (or not) and dump the pics in, its fast; and yes still a bit of editing required but it is quick. I think only the paid version allows editing in Photoshop but well worth it if you have a few to do